# Adjusting frequency of sound using Java sampled

Tags: java, slider, media-player, frequency, javax.sound.sampled

In java package sampled - using method play i want to create vertical slider which raises and lowers frequency of some predefined sound. Can anyone point me onto right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you want to do, there are mutliple ways to play a sampled sound at a different frequency.

a.) You can open a line with explicitly a different sample rate and feed your sample data into it (lets say you open a line with 22khz and feed 44khz data into it, resulting in halved pitch and the sound becomming twice as long). This method can quickly hit the limits set by the audio hardware (allowed minimum and maximum sample rate are limited).

b.) You use a line at a set sample rate and interpolate the sample data to make it longer/shorter (by inserting interpolated samples to make it longer or dropping samples to make it shorter).

c.) Use a fourier transform to transform the sound into frequency samples and reconvert that to the desired output frequency (this requires some complex math). This way, you can change the pitch of a sound while keeping its duration the same.